# Posição incorreta ao utilizar import file

Tags: javascript, html, input

Gostaria que os números do arquivo importado aparecessem na caixa celular, não abaixo, como esta aparecendo. Se alguém puder me ajudar com isso desde já agradeço.

Esse e o test:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>TEST</title>
</head>

<body>

<input type="file" id="inputCSV" onchange="pegaCSV(this)">
<div id="CSVsaida"></div>
<div class="line">

    <label>
        <span class="red">*</span>
        Celulares
    </label>
    <textarea name="msgSmsMobile" cols="35" rows="5" class="dest formulario"></textarea>
</div>
</body>
<script>

var leitorDeCSV = new FileReader()

window.onload = function init() {
    leitorDeCSV.onload = leCSV;
}

function pegaCSV(inputFile) {
    var file = inputFile.files[0];
    leitorDeCSV.readAsText(file);
}

function leCSV(evt) {

    var fileArr = evt.target.result.split('\n');
    var strDiv = '<table>';

    for (var i = 0; i < fileArr.length; i++) {
        strDiv += '<tr>';
        var fileLine = fileArr[i].split(',');
        for (var j = 0; j < fileLine.length; j++) {
            strDiv += '<td>' + fileLine[j].trim() + '</td>';
        }
        strDiv += '</tr>';
    }

    strDiv += '</table>';
    var CSVsaida = document.getElementById('CSVsaida');
    CSVsaida.innerHTML = strDiv;
}

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Breno, quando você diz na caixa, quer dizer dentro do seu textarea de nome msgSmsMobile?

Comment: isso mesmo daniel, poderia me ajudar.

Comment: Breno, consigo, mas essa formatação html que você criou, precisa existir? Pois por padrão, o textarea é texto puro, se colocar um tag, ela não ser renderizada, simplesmente vai aparecer a mesma.

Comment: Não pode ser qualquer outro tipo sem problema o importante e a página ficar funcional...

Answer (score 0):

Breno, uma maneira de colocar o texto do arquivo na textarea é a seguinte:

```js
var leitorDeCSV = new FileReader()

window.onload = function init() {
    leitorDeCSV.onload = leCSV;
}

function pegaCSV(inputFile) {
    var file = inputFile.files[0];
    leitorDeCSV.readAsText(file);
}

function leCSV(evt) {
    var csvFile = evt.target.result;
    var textArea = document.getElementById('msgSmsMobile');

    textArea.value = csvFile;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>TEST</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="file" id="inputCSV" onchange="pegaCSV(this)">
    <div class="line">

        <label>
            <span class="red">*</span>
            Celulares
        </label>

        <textarea id="msgSmsMobile" name="msgSmsMobile" cols="35" rows="5" class="dest formulario"></textarea>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Dessa forma, o conteúdo do arquivo lido, não aparece direto no body do html, ficando restrito ao textarea definido.

Comment: Ótimo, marca então a resposta como correto/aceita por favor, senão sua pergunta continua "em aberto".

Comment: como posso fechar este post?

Comment: Você não fecha, você dá o voto/aceita a resposta que lhe atendeu, assim ela consta como respondida no site.